# SQL syntax error in H2 Database when inserting array

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I am actually trying to insert the data in the H2 database. While starting up the application server, was getting the SQL syntax error exception. I am really not sure if H2 database supports the insertion of array in the column? Is there any issue with the below sql statement? Does H2 database support any of the array datatypes float[], String[]...?

```
INSERT INTO weather (id,date,temperature) values ('1','2019-09-11','{"37.3","36.8","36.4"}');

CREATE TABLE WEATHER(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
date DATE,
temperature text[]
);
```

Comment: The related Github issue regarding the array column types seems to be fixed and not yet released: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1390

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't use PostgreSQL-style `text[]` as a data type in H2 and in other databases. H2 has the `ARRAY` data type for arrays:

   https://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#array_type

   H2 1.4.201 will also support standard-compliant array data type with a component type:

   `componentDataType ARRAY[maximumCardinality]`

   You can build H2 from its current sources if you really need that functionality right now, but I think you don't really need it, non-standard plain `ARRAY` will work too.
2. `'{"37.3","36.8","36.4"}'` is a character string literal. H2 uses the standard array literals:

   `ARRAY[element, …]`

   https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#array

   If you use some outdated version of H2 you need to use non-standard `(element, …)` literal instead (but don't use that variant in recent versions, it will be parsed by them as a row value as required by the Standard).
3. It's not related with your question, but you really should use `1` instead of `'1'`  as integer literal and `DATE '2019-09-11'` instead of `'2019-09-11'` as a date literal to avoid conversions from character strings to other data types.